# Etymology of Sringa

Tags: scripture, history, etymology, art, natya-shastra

[Sringa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sringa) is an Ancient Indian musical instrument. In an answer to my [previous question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26198/which-scriptures-contain-information-about-stri-rajya), it was pointed out that Mahabharat contains a reference to a ruler of the kingdom of Stri Rajya, also known as Sringa.

With respect to this context, I have a few questions.

- What is the etymology of the word "Sringa"?
- Is there any connection between the two examples for the name (like the ruler getting the name for being an adept player of the instrument etc.)?
- What does the [Natya Shastra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natya_Shastra) say about the musical instrument Sringa?

Comment: Shringa means just a horn. It could be named because it looked like a horn. In English, it is called blowhorn and  I don't think this has anything to do with that ruler named Shringa.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma So does the ruler's name also mean horn?

Comment: Shringa means a horn of an animal, a mountain peak, highest point, pinnacle, bow horn, point of supremacy and some meanings based on he context. The only meaning that fits here for musical instrument is blow horn. We don't know about that ruler.  I don't understand why you are linking that ruler and musical instrument. There were blow horns and kettle drums before the time of Mahabharata also.

Comment: I was asking since there are a lot of examples in Indian epics and history about the name being based on a famous place/instrument/tribe etc. I suspect Rishi Panini's name is also like that. See this : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/is-sage-panini-related-to-panis

Comment: Another example is the Saka clan, which is based on Saka tree. So if the ruler's name is indeed connected to the instrument, we can just search the earliest uses of the instrument in the world and get an approximate location of Strirajya.

Comment: I already read your question about  Panini and Pani. I don't agree with your suspicion. If you want to know about that ruler, it is fine but your main question is about musical instrument which is not related to Hinduism.. There are many usages for Shringa before that ruler in Mahabharata and no evidence of relaton between that ruler and instrument.

Comment: Re : Musical instrument. Doesn't the discussion of Vedic Musical Instruments etc. fall under Natya Shastra? And there is a tag of Natya Shastra in this website...

Comment: LOL. What are Vedic instruments? You can make anything on-topic by just adding vedic before it. Discussion of musical instruments doesn't make it fall under Natya shastra unless there is a proof that this question is about Natya shastra only. You are not sure about it. There is a [music.se] to ask questions about instruments.

Comment: Re : What are Vedic Instruments? For starters, [Ancient Veena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_veena) which has been described in Rigveda, Samveda and Natya Shastra. Moreover, the Wikipedia page for Sringa says it is an ancient musical instrument, so there is reason to suspect that it might have some information about it in Natya Shastra. IMO, this is well within the topic of the site.